CX and CZ commutation
Suppose I have control qubits $1$ and $2$ and target qubit $3$. I have the circuit element
$$E = CX_{1-> 3}CZ_{2-> 3}$$
I would like to swap the order and have
$$E' = CZ_{2-> 3}CX_{1-> 3}$$
in that part of the circuit. Is there a gate acting between qubits $1$ and $2$ that I can apply before of after my circuit element $E$ so that I can replace it with $E'$ instead? If it matters, this is a stabilizer measurement circuit so the control qubits are placed in the $\vert +\rangle$ state and then one applies these controlled gates to the target qubit.
EDIT: Just wanted to remark about having the operation constrained to be between qubits $1$ and $2$ - otherwise, I can trivially do a $CZ_{2->3}$ before and after $E$ to get the desired order.

$E$ is the map given by  $E|i,j\rangle |\psi \rangle  = |i,j\rangle Z^j X^i |\psi \rangle$.
$E'$ is the map given by $E'|i,j\rangle |\psi \rangle  = |i,j\rangle X^i Z^j  |\psi \rangle = (-1)^{ij}|i,j\rangle  Z^j X^i |\psi \rangle  = CZ_{1,2}\, E$. So performing a $CZ_{1,2}$ on either side of $E$ will give you $E'$

$$CX=(I\otimes H) CZ( I\otimes H)$$ So we can express $$CX_{1,3}CZ_{2,3}=(I\otimes I\otimes H) CZ_{1,3}(I\otimes I\otimes H) CZ_{2,3}$$
By the first identity I showed, $CX=(I\otimes H) CZ( I\otimes H)$ so $CX(I\otimes H)=(I\otimes H) CZ$
So $$(I\otimes I\otimes H) CZ_{1,3}(I\otimes I\otimes H) CZ_{2,3}=(I\otimes I\otimes H) CZ_{1,3} CX_{2,3}(I\otimes I\otimes H)$$
Now from here we can use swap gates to change the control qubits.
$$(I\otimes I\otimes H)SWAP_{1,2}CZ_{1,3}SWAP_{1,2}^{\dagger}SWAP_{1,2} CX_{2,3}SWAP_{1,2}^{\dagger}(I\otimes I\otimes H)$$
Now $CZ_{1,3}$ will have the second qubit as it's control, so will be $CZ_{2,3}$, and $CX_{2,3}$ will have the first qubit as it's control,  so will be $CX_{1,3}$
Edit:
I'm going to leave this but I like the other answer better. More concise and seems more in line with what you are asking. I just seen commutation of the gates and went down my thought process.
